# which exception will be thrown??answer is given finally Exception but why not tryException

Tags: java

```
try

{

throw tryException();

}

catch

{

throw catchException();

}
finally

{

throw finallyException();

}
```

Comment: No matter what finally always executes (unless you do System.exit() in try). That's the reason.

Answer (score 0):

According to the official Java Documentation:

"The finally block always executes when the try block exits. This ensures that the finally block is executed even if an unexpected exception occurs."

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html

Answer (score 0):

The finally exception will be thrown except under the condition Suresh Atta has stated in the comments; System.exit() is called, which will abruptly terminate the program.

Remember in the absence of System.exit(), the finally block always runs after the catch block.

As the finally block is ran last, the exception thrown in the finally block will be thrown.

N.B: You can have try, finally block without a catch block.